# Damage to front end suspension

Tags: suspension, damage

This is a duplicate of a question I posted a month ago. The answer I got stated that I could get a better answer  if I provided pictures of the incident. I have attached a picture in hopes of getting a more insightful answer regarding a bolt through my front end suspension
Questions:
enter image description here Left drivers side Control Arm replacement[image]
What type of structural damage so this do to the vehicle?
If the nut was difficult to remove does it require a specialized set of tools and a high level of expertise to be repaired properly.
What type of hazard could this create when operating the vehicle?

Comment: You should have edited your original question rather than making a duplicate question

Comment: Yes, please update your original question with the new information.